# responsive accordions are not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

my custom responsive accordions are not working. Requirement is to have heading and content for the desktop view but if it loads on smaller device will turn to accordions. I have just achieved it. But when I re-size the window it doesn't work well and functionality behaves weird animation and sometime it does't work.

Can anyone please help me to find out what is the problem in my code?

Below are jsBin URL and js code:

URL:

http://jsbin.com/zarak/5/edit

Code:

```
if($(window).width() < 360){
   $('h2').on('click', function() {

                var _target = $(this).next('.reponsiveTap');
                if(_target.css('display') == 'none'){
                    _target.slideDown();
                    $(this).addClass('active');
                }else{
                    _target.slideUp();
                    $(this).removeClass('active');
                }               

            });  
  }

else if($(window).width() > 359){
    $('h2').on('click', function() {

      return false;

    });

  }

$(window).resize(function(){

  if($(window).width() < 360){
   $('h2').on('click', function() {

                var _target = $(this).next('.reponsiveTap');
                if(_target.css('display') == 'none'){
                    _target.slideDown();
                    $(this).addClass('active');
                }else{
                    _target.slideUp();
                    $(this).removeClass('active');
                }               

            });  
  }

else if($(window).width() > 359){
    $('h2').on('click', function() {

      return false;

    });

  }

});
```

Many thanks,
Mufeed Ahmad

Answer (score 0):

Try this, here's a <kbd>**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/mdesdev/DSXm3/)**</kbd>

```
$(window).resize(function() {
  if($(this).width() < 360) {
     $('.reponsiveTap').slideUp(400, 'linear');

     $('.in-row h2').on('click', function() {
       $('.reponsiveTap').stop().slideUp(400, 'linear').removeClass('active');
       $(this).next('.reponsiveTap').stop().slideToggle(400, 'linear').addClass('active');
     });
  }
  else {
     $('.reponsiveTap').slideDown(400, 'linear');
     $('.in-row h2').off('click');
  }
});
```